# Android, Realm: Method "copyToRealmOrUpdate" not update only delta

Tags: android, realm

Android application.

When I want to create or update my POJO to Realm I use the method: **copyToRealmOrUpdate**. OK.

But now I want to update only changed fields (not all). Method **copyToRealmOrUpdate** replace ALL fields. But I need to update only delta.
How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do something like that.
Propably you have to replace whole object.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update only a few fields, then you need to query the object and update only some of its fields, instead of overwriting the whole object.

```
r.executeTransaction((realm) -> {
    MyObject myObj = realm.where(MyObject.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirst();
    if(myObj == null) {
        myObj = realm.createObject(MyObject.class, id);
    }
    myObj.setDeltaField(newValue);
    // other fields
});
```